# Is there a way to suppress a vertical line across sections in Crystal Report 8.0?

Tags: suppress

I want to suppress a vertical line when a condition is met. This vertical line crosses two sections, the Report Section and the Detail Section.

I have no problem suppressing horizontal line because I can just hide the section where it lies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the condition report-wide?

Comment: It spans up to two sections. What I did was create a new section before the vertical line, inserted a blank textbox then set Underlay Following Sections.